# Getting the formula of a live counter

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graph-theory, regression

I'm looking to replicate this [greenhouse gases counter](http://www.dbcca.com/dbcca/EN/) in my website. Poking around i found the initial data for the formula.

The counter use the following information:

- Beginnig date: 2012/03/01
- End date: 2012/04/01
- Begin count: 3698043054083
- End Count: 3699966291242

I tried to do a linear regression like this:

```
m = (xf - xi) / (tf - ti)
conter = m*(t-ti)+xi
```

here's the [result](http://www.activomultimedia.com/publik/counter.swf), but my counter keeps falling behind (probably the original isn't a linear formula).

Is there a better way to replicate this counter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not doing your calculations in Greenwich Mean Time (Z).

I assume the start and end numbers are at 00:00 on the days in question, and an increase of 1,923,237,159 over the 31 days of March is about 62,039,908.35 increase each day.  After 24 days and 21 hours and 30 minutes, i.e about 24.895833 days, I would expect a figure of 3,699,587,589,301.  It is 3,699,587,588,394, close enough for me.

Comment: Looks like it is a problem with the time indeed. Thanks a lot. :)